# flutter package can not find classes in package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am trying to create a flutter package.

Inside Lib(package) folder, I have `MY-PACKAGE.dart` file. I also have a folder Called `src` which contains some codes I will import for use in `MY-PACKAGE.dart`.

In my `pubspec.yaml` in `Example folder` I have added the package like below and run packages get.

```
onboardly:
  path: ../
```

To use my package I do this

```
// THERE IS NOT ANY PROBLEM WITH THIS IMPORT STATEMENT
import 'package:onboardly/onboardly.dart';

        OnBoardly(       // THIS CLASS WORKS FINE
          screens: [
             OnBoardlyScreenItem(   // THIS CLASS CAN NOT BE FOUND EVEN THO IT EXISTS IN THE src FOLDER
             image: Image.asset("assets/loadicon.png"),
             description: Text("Hello There"),
             ),
          ],
        ),
```

The problem am facing is the fact that  `OnBoardlyScreenItem()` which is in the `src` of the package can not be found.

I have ran
`flutter packages get`
`flutter pub get`
`restarted my IDE`
run `flutter clean`

[image: The File Structure]

Comment: Did you export the class? Is it accessible in other sub-packages of the same package? Could you please share the declarations of the class?

Comment: Can you please share the file and folder structure

Comment: code under `src` is considered private to the library [Docs](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages)

Comment: Thanks @dev-aentgs. Its private so I had to export it

Comment: thanks @SanjaySharma. I had not exported it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this for anyone later,

I had to export those classes or files that I wanted to be available to the Package to the "Entry file" since the folders in my case are regarded as private. Export all files or classes you'll want to be available to the user.

```
// Exporting all codes to be avaible to package
export 'package:onboardly/src/IntroScreen/OnBoardlyScreenItem.dart';
```